# What if my post does not get answers?

Tags: discussion, user-information

What to do in that case? As far as I know, there is no way to request a particular member to answer my question. I put this up nearly a day and a half ago

[Wedge constraint relations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/511939/wedge-constraint-relations)

No one answered, and this post has moved way down the list. What should I do? Should I delete and repost it?

It's not just about my post. This caters to anyone who does not get answers to their questions on there.

Comment: Adding a bounty is the normal solution if you absolutely need an answer. Definitely don't delete and repost it.

Comment: Only a day and a half? I have lots of questions waiting months or years for answers! You've gotta be more patient.

Comment: @jhpratt thank you. So adding a bounty is the only option I guess?

Comment: @curiousdannii Months or years? I'm a student so I can't wait that long to learn a concept that I need to learn now

Comment: @πtimese If you need to learn something quickly for school or university, talk to your teacher/lecturer/tutor, that's their job!

Comment: @curiousdanni right. But what if I still don't get the concept? First I talk to my teachers before posting it on here. I never post anything without discussing with my teachers first. I can wait 3 or 4 days, or a week. But definitely can't months or years. Wouldn't help a student, you know

Comment: Then ask your teachers for *more* help. Keep asking, until you understand.

Comment: @curiousdannii I discuss all my doubts with them, until it all makes sense to me. However, sometimes I still can't understand a particular thing, or I just want to understand it differently, from a different frame, for example. That's one of the reasons I post my doubts here. It's not that I am wasting my time. You're not making sense. I'm not wasting my time here. My time is very valuable, just like yours, just like everyone else's

Comment: Here's some tips, (I haven't read any of your questions, so you might be doing this for all I know). When you write a question for the first time, it's a good idea to provide the context in the first paragraph. Explain **why** you are asking, **show which research** you have done so far, say why that research didn't help, say what your **teachers have told you**. Do that in one or two paragraphs, properly **format** the content, **check for typos**, misspellings, and grammar (because it shows you *care* and respect your readers), **revise** the post at least three times before posting.

Comment: I would have posted the comment as an answer but your question is closed.

Answer (score 5):

Please do not delete and re-post it -- if you do that, we will end up undeleting the old one, marking the new one as a duplicate of the old, and leaving a stern comment somewhere.

You can add a bounty if you would like to spend some of your rep to encourage others to answer it. But, it is better to reflect on the question itself and try to improve it. Make it clearer, make it more interesting, make it more useful for future readers. Edits will bump it back to the front page.

As it stands, it seems like you are looking for help on a homework problem and that doesn't usually go over well on Physics.SE. The sense of urgency after just 24 hours doesn't help that impression...

It is possible to ask good homework questions there though. Check out the [Physics Meta site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com) and search for homework -- you'll find plenty of advice. You can also hop into chat to get help/feedback on improving the question.

Comment: I'm not deleting and reposting it. I was just asking if that's what everyone does. Thanks for letting me know about the bounty. And no, it's not a homework question. You can read my post. It's not a homework question. It's about a specific concept that I am not able to understand

Comment: @πtimese Physics [takes a broad view of what is considered "homework"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) -- it doesn't have to be something that is literally assigned for a grade. I've read your question and it fits the definition we use for homework-and-exercises (but it isn't off-topic per se). I suspect I know why it hasn't gotten much attention, but this site here isn't the venue to discuss that. If you edit it to improve the question, it will get bumped and will get eyes on it again -- for better, or for worse.

Comment: I have read it before, the whole thing. The definition of homework according to what it says "A homework question is any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved, rather than getting the answer itself" I don't understand how my post fits the definition. My post is not about solving a numerical question or solving any question at all. It is about a specific physics concept (constraint relations) that didn't make sense to me, and that's what my post is about. I truly don't see how my post fits the definition of homework questions

Comment: thanks though. I didn't know about things like the bounty system, etc. Now I do, thanks to you

Comment: @πtimese  Editing an old post (good tip) bumps it on the active page, and that can help draw attention. But avoid using it repeatedly because some users get annoyed by seeing the same question for a couple of days and will downvote.